# Running grails from STS shows Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I was using grails 2.0.3 with all the environment variables set. Then, I wanted  to shift into a new grails version 2.3.7 and I modified each environment setting to point to `2.3.7` including my `STS`.

Grails console showed up and generated my domains inside `STS`. But when trying to `run-app` it displays the following error and quits.

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : null
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

PS: grails->refresh dependency / clean and build all works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reason:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3739

Springloaded jar was moved and renamed in Grails 2.3.7. GGTS 3.4.0 (or earlier) can't find it.

This bug is fixed in 3.5.0.

These are your options:

1) keep using older version of Grails (<=2.3.6)

2) Download and use GGTS 3.5.1 release.

This information came from here:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/745972-sts-3-4-0-and-grails-2-3-7-run-app-broken?p=746042#post746042

I just updated it a little to reflect that 3.5.1 release is now available.