# error while upgrading grails 2.3.0 to 2.3.8

Tags: grails, upgrade

I upgraded grails2.3.0 to 2.3.8 but when i try  `run-app`  it gives the following error.

```
  Error occurred during initialization of VM
  agent library failed to init: instrumentError 
  opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : null
```

any solution thank you!!!

currently am using STS-3.1.0

Comment: Are you doing this from the command line?  Give the command line a try and see what that produces.  Otherwise I would delete your 2.3.8 and download and reinstall for starters.

Comment: @Joe yes i changed the environments from terminal.  i checked grails -version it is working. but the i think the project is missing something

Comment: Are you saying that run-app generates this error from the command line?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  it runs correctly from terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the spring loaded jar changed a couple of times and the IDE needs to adapt when that happens.  If this is happening from the IDE you should update your STS (better yet, use GGTS) to the latest versions of the Groovy and Grails tooling and this problem should go away.  You could also copy the spring loaded jar to the location that the IDE expects, but that is a bit of a hack.  Updating the IDE is a better idea.

Comment: i downloaded the update springsource-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-updatesite   now how do i update the current sts version using the update.  just extract and put it in the same folder..is that it??

Answer (score 0):

According to my observation working on grails and STS . new version come after the 2.3.7 and including fail to run on STS 3.3.x and Version prior to that.This applies the same to GGTS of similar version. I have been asking the same question but , the solution dosent come at handy. Any way try to upgrade with care and Before that check the following:

check you environment varible if you have defined or set the new grails path to 2.3.7 and test it on command line .

You can still run apps on command line though  or switch IDE like IntelJ.

[See this question of mine here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582882/running-grails-from-sts-shows-error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing)